# Make SQL Update from SQL Select

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to convert the following SQL Select into SQL Update as follows:

```
SELECT P.Partno, SUM(D.Qty_ordered) - SUM(Qty_rec) as QTY_ONORDER
   FROM Parts P
    LEFT JOIN PoDet D ON P.Partno = D.Partno
    LEFT JOIN PoRec R ON D.PoDet_pk = R.PoDet_pk
   GROUP BY P.Partno
```

I need to update the column ONORDER of the table Parts, setting the value to SUM(D.QTY_Ordered) - SUM(QTY_REC).  That is, set the value to the current on-order quantity.

I tried the following (but I get error):

```
UPDATE P P.ONORDER = SUM(D.Qty_ordered) - SUM(Qty_rec) 
   FROM Parts P
    LEFT JOIN PoDet D ON P.Partno = D.Partno
    LEFT JOIN PoRec R ON D.PoDet_pk = R.PoDet_pk
   GROUP BY P.Partno
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Can you post the error.

Comment: The error is:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: Your update is missing "SET"

Answer (score 2):

You need to do aggregation in a subquery.  I assume the quantities are coming from the two tables being `join`ed in.  If so, your version will produce a Cartesian product -- and if there is more than one row for a given part in either table, the numbers will be off.

I think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE P
   SET P.ONORDER = COALESCE(d.qty, 0) - COALESCE(r.qty, 0)) 
   FROM Parts P LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT D.PartNo, SUM(D.Qty_ordered) as qty
         FROM PoDet D
         GROUP BY d.PartNo
        ) D
        ON P.Partno = D.Partno LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT D.PartNo, SUM(R.Qty_rec) as qty
         FROM PoDet D JOIN
              PoRec R
              ON D.PoDet_pk = R.PoDet_pk
         GROUP BY D.PartNo
        ) R
        ON P.PartNo = R.PartNo;
```

Comment: First, thank you. What confuses me in your code is that PoRec does not have column PartNo. It has column PoDet_PK, foreign key to the table PODET.

Comment: @Hidalgo . . . I see that now.  I updated the query.  This form is needed if you can have multiple matches in `PoDet` for a single part.

Comment: Gordon, sorry again. But the last part of your code "ON P.PoDet_pk = R.PartNo" is not correct. Table P (Parts) does not have column PoDet_PK.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `SET` keyword in `update` statement also thats not a valid syntax

Try this syntax

```
UPDATE up
SET    up.ONORDER = QTY_ONORDER
FROM   Parts up
       INNER JOIN (SELECT P.Partno,
                          Sum(D.Qty_ordered) - Sum(Qty_rec) AS QTY_ONORDER
                   FROM   Parts P
                          LEFT JOIN PoDet D
                                 ON P.Partno = D.Partno
                          LEFT JOIN PoRec R
                                 ON D.PoDet_pk = R.PoDet_pk
                   GROUP  BY P.Partno) A
               ON up.Partno = A.Partno
```

Answer (score 1):

The is nothing wrong with Fireblade's answer, I just thought I would contribute an alternate approach - easier for a beginner (and me) to follow

```
-- create the results
SELECT P.Partno, SUM(D.Qty_ordered) - SUM(Qty_rec) as QTY_ONORDER
INTO #tmp
   FROM Parts P
    LEFT JOIN PoDet D ON P.Partno = D.Partno
    LEFT JOIN PoRec R ON D.PoDet_pk = R.PoDet_pk
   GROUP BY P.Partno

-- apply
UPDATE P
SET ONORDER=#tmp.QTY_ONORDER
FROM P
JOIN #tmp ON P.PartNo=#tmp.Partno

-- clean
DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

A crude (but readable) way to do it would be something like this:

```
UPDATE Parts set ONORDER = (select SUM(D.Qty_ordered) - SUM(Qty_rec) 
   FROM PoDet D
    LEFT JOIN PoRec R ON D.PoDet_pk = R.PoDet_pk
    where D.Partno = Parts.Partno)
```

Answer (score 0):

i bet this is what you mean

```
UPDATE P 
   set P.ONORDER = SUM(D.Qty_ordered - R.Qty_rec) 
   FROM Parts P
    LEFT JOIN PoDet D ON P.Partno = D.Partno
    LEFT JOIN PoRec R ON D.PoDet_pk = R.PoDet_pk
   GROUP BY P.Partno
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I missed SET in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

Just using your queries :

```
UPDATE P set P.ONORDER = temp.QTY_ONORDER
from 
( 
 SELECT P.Partno as part, SUM(D.Qty_ordered) - SUM(Qty_rec) as QTY_ONORDER
 FROM Parts P
 LEFT JOIN PoDet D ON P.Partno = D.Partno
 LEFT JOIN PoRec R ON D.PoDet_pk = R.PoDet_pk
 GROUP BY P.Partno 
) temp
where temp.part = P.Partno ;
```